# Guzzle doesn't return any response in Laravel Lumen project

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to post data to a controller in my Laravel Lumen 8 project which uses Guzzle 7.4, when posting data to my API I'm not getting any response back and it seems to timeout after my 5 seconds, even if I change my timeout to something like 30 seconds it will religiously wait 30 seconds and then time out, if I try to post to my endpoint using postman without PHP then I get a response back instantly, what am I missing?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Report;
use Carbon\Carbon;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ReportsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Instantiate a new ReportsController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // $this->middleware('before:view');
    }

    /**
     * Get API url
     */
    protected function getApiUrl()
    {
        return rtrim(config('fudge.fudge_api_domain'), '/');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $api = $this->getApiUrl();
        $token = $request->input('token');
        if (!$token && $request->header('Authorization')) {
            $token = explode(' ', $request->header('Authorization'))[1];
        }

        $client = new Client([
            'timeout' => 5
        ]);

        $response = $client->post('http://localhost:8000/api/hub/login', [
            'form_params' => [
                'token' => 'my token',
                'ability' => "reports:view"
            ]
        ]);

        // the response
        // $res = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);

        return response()->json([
            'res' => json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true)
        ], 200);

        // $hasAbility = isset($res['has_ability']) && !empty($res['has_ability']) ? $res['has_ability'] : false;
        //
        //
        // if (!$hasAbility) {
        //     return response()->json([
        //         'message' => "You're not authorised"
        //     ], 401);
        // }

        // $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        //     'report' => 'required|in:ConsolidateAverageConversions',
        // ]);
        //
        // if ($validator->fails()) {
        //     return response()->json([
        //         'message' => "It looks like you've missed something.",
        //         'errors' => $validator->messages()
        //     ], 400);
        // }

        // $report = Report::where('report_type', $request->input('report'))
        //                 ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        //                 ->first();
        //
        // if (!$report) {
        //     return response()->json([
        //         'message' => "This report doesn't exist or is invalid"
        //     ], 404);
        // }
        //
        // return response()->json([
        //     'report' => $report
        // ], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you've shown running? I mean is it part of the same application it POSTs to at `http://localhost:8000/`? How are you accessing the `index()` method that fires that POST?  Does the token stuff work, and are you really meant to be using `my token` instead of `$token`? Are you seeing any hits in your web server, PHP, or application logs on the `http://localhost:8000/` end?  Have you tried debugging the Guzzle call, checking the request etc?

Comment: BTW it seems that 90% of the code you've posted is not relevant to the problem (commented out or empty methods).  You'll make it easier for ppl to help if you [include only the stuff relevant to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (just your `index()` method, AFAICT?).